# Why don't my simple code work in C++?

Tags: c++

Error in function realloc(): invalid pointer

```
int indZero = 0; 

int *perZero=NULL;

int zero = 0;//Initialization


ProcessBit(zero,&indZero,&perZero);// Call function

void ProcessBit(int num,int *ind,int **mas)

{

mas=(int**)realloc(&mas,((*ind))*sizeof(int));// Error

mas[num-1]++;//it's correct line

}
```

Comment: Also, this code is not in c++, it's in C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few problems:

- The first argument to [`realloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) is the *original* pointer (or `NULL`).
- Your `ProcessBit` doesn't really emulate pass-by-reference correctly.
- You can use a negative index.
- `mas` is a pointer to a pointer to `int`, but you use it as a pointer to `int`.

A "fixed" version *might* look something like this:

```
void ProcessBit(int num, int *ind, int **mas)
{
    int *temp = realloc(*mas, (*ind + 1) * sizeof(int));
    if (temp == NULL)
    {
        // TODO: Handle error
        // TODO: return or exit(EXIT_FAILURE)
    }

    *mas = temp;

    (*mas)[*ind] = 0;  // Initial initialization

    if (num > 0)
    {
        (*mas)[num - 1]++;
    }

    ++*ind;  // Increase the size
}
```

---

Now, if this really was C++ (as you tagged your question) then you should be using [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead, which would solve almost all your problems with much simpler code.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters are wrong. Since you are trying to realloc a NULL pointer it should behave like malloc; however, the header declared in cstdlib is

```
void* realloc( void* ptr, std::size_t new_size );
```

The formal parameter `mas` is already the **address** of the pointer, so the call should be

```
*mas=(int*)realloc(*mas,((*ind))*sizeof(int));
(*mas)[num-1]++;
```

Since realloc handles and returns pointers **by copy**, not by reference.

You are passing the address of the memory location where the address of a memory location (NULL) is stored to your `ProcessBit` function, and then the address of that location to the `realloc` function. The function tries to reallocate memory where the variable `mac` is stored, on the stack. No wonder it's an invalid pointer.

By passing `&mac` you are simply taking a step in the wrong direction while dereferencing pointers.